# Union of $\sqrt[n]{z}$ and $\sqrt[n]{-z}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $z$ be a complex number. Prove that the union of $\sqrt[n]{z}$ and $\sqrt[n]{-z}$ is $\sqrt[2n]{z^2}$.

I know that $\sqrt[n]{z}=\left\{\sqrt[n]{r}\left(\cos\left(\frac{\varphi+2k\pi}{n}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\varphi+2k\pi}{n}\right)\right),\quad k=1,\dots,n\right\}$ and $\sqrt[n]{-z}=\left\{\sqrt[n]{r}\left(-\cos\left(\frac{\varphi+2k\pi}{n}\right)-i\sin\left(\frac{\varphi+2k\pi}{n}\right)\right),\quad k=1,\dots,n\right\}$, but how do I take the union of those two sets and show it is equal to $\sqrt[2n]{z^2}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here $\sqrt[n]{z}$ is understood as the set of all complex numbers $w$ satisfying $w^n = z$, and similarly for the other expressions.

So what we need to show is that
$$
 \{ w \in \Bbb C \mid w^n = z \} \cup  \{ w \in \Bbb C \mid w^n = -z \} 
=  \{ w \in \Bbb C \mid w^{2n} = z^2 \} \, ,
$$
i.e. that
$$
 (w^n = z \text{ or } w^n = -z) \iff w^{2n} = z^2
$$
holds for all complex numbers $w$ and $z$. And that is true because
$$
(w^n = z \text{ or } w^n = -z) \iff (w^n-z)(w^z+z) = 0 \\
 \iff w^{2n} - z^2 = 0 \iff w^{2n} = z^2 \, .
$$